# Abelian group action on a projective space

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian Lie subgroup of the projective linear group $\mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb C)=\mathrm {Aut} (\mathbb CP^n) $. Are  the orbits of $G$ in $\mathbb CP^n$ closed? (acting by group automorphisms)